# How to alter primary key column in SQL Server using T-SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to remove a column from primary key? I am not talking about `Alter` a primary key constraint. I just want to free a column from primary key using T-SQL script. I can do it by modifying the column by right click on column name. but can't do the same task using T-SQL Script. Is there any idea how to accomplish this task?

Comment: Drop and Recreate the `Index` is the only possible way

Comment: Is it the right way? because I can remove the primary key using management studio.

Comment: Perhaps the studio is doing things under the hood along the lines of what @Prdp mentioned.

Comment: I can drop the key :)

Comment: If you have tables referencing your table (via a foreign key), then you must first drop all the referencing foreign keys, drop the primary key and re-create it, and then re-create all those referencing foreign keys. But this can all be done in T-SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using T-SQL. Let's say your table name is `branch`.

So first we will get primary key constraint name using following query:

**Query**

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.key_constraints
WHERE [type] = 'PK'
  AND [parent_object_id] = Object_id('dbo.branch');
```

**Result**

```
'PK_Branch'
```

Now we use that result in another query to drop primary key. This query will remove primary key from `branch` table.

**Query**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.branch
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Branch
```

Comment: This works as long as **no other tables** reference `dbo.branch`. If you have tables referencing it (via a foreign key), then you must first drop all the referencing foreign keys, drop the primary key and re-create it, and then re-create all those referencing foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Drop and Recreate the `Index` is the only way to do, even with Management Studio.

From Management Studio, right click a table, choose Design and see the Interface. After make some changes, before Saves your changes, right click on table Design and choose "Generate Change Script..." you will see what Management Studio do, "behind the scenes".
It's actually drop table, re-create it with new Changes and add in data back to the table.